# Yii Framework formbuilder - is there any way to change inputID in validation javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, frameworks, yii, formbuilder

Is there any way to change inputID in validation javascript when using form builder in Yii?

My problem is that I have two similar forms (using one form builder code) on one page. 
It's login form, used twice.
First, in template (shown on every page of website) and second - the same form, used in /site/login page (this page is used to redirect user in case of access restritions etc).

This two forms work fine, but yii generates validation javascript with the same inputID for elements of two form, and i don't know how to change it.
Take a look:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
jQuery('a[rel="popover"]').popover();
$('#loginForm').yiiactiveform({'attributes':[{'id':'LoginForm_email','inputID':'LoginForm_email','errorID':'LoginForm_email_em_','model':'LoginForm','name':'LoginForm[email]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'LoginForm_password','inputID':'LoginForm_password','errorID':'LoginForm_password_em_','model':'LoginForm','name':'LoginForm[password]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'LoginForm_rememberMe','inputID':'LoginForm_rememberMe','errorID':'LoginForm_rememberMe_em_','model':'LoginForm','name':'LoginForm[rememberMe]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}]});
$('#quickLoginForm').yiiactiveform({'attributes':[{'id':'LoginForm_email','inputID':'LoginForm_email','errorID':'LoginForm_email_em_','model':'LoginForm','name':'LoginForm[email]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'LoginForm_password','inputID':'LoginForm_password','errorID':'LoginForm_password_em_','model':'LoginForm','name':'LoginForm[password]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'LoginForm_rememberMe','inputID':'LoginForm_rememberMe','errorID':'LoginForm_rememberMe_em_','model':'LoginForm','name':'LoginForm[rememberMe]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}]});
jQuery('#collapse_0').collapse({'parent':false,'toggle':false});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

And that's the problem. I can't understand, how to change this:
     `'id':'LoginForm_email','inputID':'LoginForm_email',`
to:
     `'id':'quickLoginForm_email','inputID':'quickLoginForm_email',`
to make validation work for two forms.
I have tried to change form id, form title, element id, element name (ofc) but with no result.
Is it possible to change it dynamicaly, without changing form file name etc?
I tried to read CActiveForm sources, but I didn't find where it takes the inputID.

Ofc it's possible not to show layout form on /site/login page, but it's not the best way I think.

Answer (score 1):

So, after 3-4 hours of reading Yii sources, let me post answer to my own question.
The first thing we want to change in generated javascript is error inputID.
Like mashingan wrote, if you are not using form builder, you can set in $form->error.
If you are using form builder, you can access error options from errorOptions property of CFormInputElement class:

```
    'elements'=>array(
        'email'=>array(
            'id'=>$this->id.'_email',
            'name'=>$this->id.'[email]',
            'type'=>'text',
            'maxlength'=>32,
            'label'=>false,
            'placeholder'=>'Your email address',            
            'errorOptions'=>array('inputID'=>$this->id.'_email','id'=>$this->id.'_email'),
        ),
```

Note that by default you can't access form id or something from this array.
You have to send your $this->id (or name it whatever you want) when constructing form object. I have created MyForm class, extending CForm, with constructor:

```
class MyForm extends CForm
{
public $id;
public function __construct($config, $model = null, $parent = null, $id = null) {
    if($id != null) $this->id = $id;
    parent::__construct($config, $model, $parent);
}
```

And then I am creating my form in layout:

```
$quickLoginForm = new MyForm('application.views.site.loginForm', $model, null, 'QuickLoginForm');
```

or

```
$loginForm = new MyForm('application.views.site.loginForm', $model, null, 'LoginForm');
```

The example above will allow you to dynamically change inputID and errorID in validation javascript generated by Yii.

Let's now look to our JS generated by yii:

```
'id':'LoginForm_email','inputID':'QuickLoginForm_email','errorID':'QuickLoginForm_email'
```

We have changed inputID and errorID, and next thing we have to change to make our validation work for two same forms is 'id'.

But how? There is no information about this in documentation.
Let's look into CActiveForm->error() sources:

```
...
$id=CHtml::activeId($model,$attribute);
...
```

Ok, so what CHtml::activeId does?

```
public static function activeId($model,$attribute)
{
    return self::getIdByName(self::activeName($model,$attribute));
}
```

...

```
public static function activeName($model,$attribute)
{
    $a=$attribute; // because the attribute name may be changed by resolveName
    return self::resolveName($model,$a);
}
```

...

```
public static function resolveName($model,&$attribute)
{
...
    return get_class($model).'['.$attribute.']';
}
```

It's f*cking genius! They take model name to use in generated javascript.
Not form id, not element name, they use model class name!

I don't know, what Qiang Xue have smoked, but if you want to make validation javascript work for two same forms on one page, you have to make two same models.

So, it we want to change 'id' in javascript, we have to make this:

```
<?php
class QuickLoginForm extends LoginForm
{
}
```

(LoginForm is our model) And use in when generating second form.

```
$quickLoginModel=new QuickLoginForm;
$quickLoginForm = new MyForm('application.views.site.loginForm', $quickLoginModel, null, 'QuickLoginForm');
```

Congratulations!
After making two hacks we have got our validation javascript working for two same forms.
I don't know how to speak about code reusage or name Yii "extandable framework", if you can't just make two login forms on one page without jumping like a monkey around the source code of yii javascript generator.

Answer (score 1):

We were having the same issue, however doing an extensive research we found out that Yii already supports changing the InputID so that your validations work.

However the documentation was not done yet.

To fix it, the only thing we had to do was to setup the InputID in the error field to correspond to the id you have setup in your attribute field. Like this:

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'attribute',array('inputID'=>'custom-id')); ?>
```

The documentation for this change will now be available after Yii 1.1.14 is released. In the meantime if you do what we did it should work.

Hope this works for anyone with the same issue.

References:

1 Qiang Xue description on how to reproduce the problem. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/158

2 mdomba documentation commit to the github repository. This explains how to fix your code: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/commit/65b9bd06e885b96cc08922282b79a9c78484a9bd

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'attr', array('id' => 'someId')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'attr', array('inputID' => 'someId')); ?>
```

Don't forget to keep `input.id` and `error.inputID` the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not work for Form Builder http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder